# yii2 array of models in Active Form

Tags: yii2

Assume that I have a page user create ,I want to multi create user on single views ,It mean that when submit form ,multi instances of model will be sent to controller to do saving,
how can I accomplish it with Yii2
anything like this

```
public function actionMultiCreate() {
   if($request->isGet) {
      $user = new User()
      return $this->render("multi-create",['user' => $user]) 
   } else {
     //load array of user model and save it
   }
}
```

and views :

```
....
User1: <$form->field($model,'user-name')>
User2: <$form->field($model,'user-name')>
......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is based on loadMultiple

```
public function actionCreate()
{
     if (Model::loadMultiple($items, Yii::$app->request->post()) && 
        Model::validateMultiple($items)) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
           // populate and save records for each model
            $item->save()) 
        }
    }  
    ........

    .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,I have another question ,how do I declare an array of model instance and send it to view?

Comment: In SO is fair post a single well defined question .. so if my answer is right please mark it as accepted and for the second questio please provide a proper well defined new post so all the community can help you

Comment: Thanks for your support